# How to dynamically add Nodes to VBox in ScalaFX

Tags: scala, scalafx

My ScalaFX app has a `Button` that adds a `GridPane` to a `VBox`. I tried directly updating the `VBox` children in `Button.onAction` but that causes the `Button` to become non-responsive after rendering the first added `GridPane`. I am now trying the following code:

```
import scalafx.scene.{Node, Scene}
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.geometry.Insets
import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, Label}
import scalafx.scene.layout.{GridPane, VBox}
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer

object Gui extends JFXApp {

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "DSP Lab"
    scene = new Scene(320, 300) {

      val bufferOfNodes = new ObservableBuffer[Node]

      val vBox = new VBox {
        children = bufferOfNodes // assign ObservableBuffer to children
      }

      val addGridPaneButton = new Button {
        text = "Add GridPane to VBox"
        onAction = _ => {
          bufferOfNodes += getNewGridPane // update the ObservableBuffer
        }
      }

      content = List(addGridPaneButton, vBox)
    }
  }

  stage.setX(100)
  stage.setY(100)

  def getNewGridPane: GridPane = new GridPane {
    vgap = 5
    hgap = 10
    padding = Insets(20)

    val sampleFrequencyLabel = new Label("Sample Frequency:")
    val sampleFrequencyField = new DoubleField
    val amplitudeLabel = new Label("Amplitude:")
    val amplitudeField = new DoubleField
    add(sampleFrequencyLabel, 0, 0)
    add(sampleFrequencyField, 1, 0)
    add(amplitudeLabel, 0, 1)
    add(amplitudeField, 1, 1)
  }
}
```

By assigning `VBox.children` to the `ObservableBuffer[Node]` the `Button` stays responsive and `onAction` adds the `GridPane` to `bufferOfNodes` but the `GridPane`s seem to never get added to the `VBox` and they are never rendered.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was asked and answered on ScalaFX-Users mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer&pli=1#!topic/scalafx-users/3IzGAnflUnU